# Building with runtime flags using cabal and ghc

Tags: haskell, build, ghc, cabal

I have a program written in Haskell and intended to be compiled with GHC. The program scales very well on multiple cores, so enabling multithreading is very important. In my `.cabal` file I've added `ghc-options: -O3 -threaded` to link with the threaded runtime. The problem is that with this approach the user would need to run the program with `foo +RTS -N`, which seems a bit cryptic and not very user friendly.

How can I tell cabal/ghc to enable those runtime flags invisibly to the user? I've read about `--with-rtsopts`, but GHC (7.0.3) just spits out `unrecognized flag` when I try to use it.

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The flag is `-with-rtsopts`, not `--with-rtsopts`, so you should add `-with-rtsopts=-N` to the ghc-options field.  [GHC Flag Reference.](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/7.0.1/html/users_guide/runtime-control.html)

Note that this will also require you to link with runtime support by adding `-rtsopts` to the ghc-options.

Comment: Thank you, this helped me! I also tried enabling the `-g1` flag with `-with-rtsopts="-N -g1"` but then I get `unrecognized flag: -g1`. Both `-N` and `-g1` work fine separately.

Comment: @Viktor Dahl: I think the quotes are causing the problem.  Try either using single quotes, or multiple `-with-rtsopts` lines.  If that solves it, it's probably a ghc bug (or documentation error).

Comment: Single quotes didn't solve it, but using two `-with-rtsopts` did.

Comment: Looks like a cabal bug: If you write `-with-rtsopts="-flagA -flagB"` it calls GHC with `'-with-rtspots="-flagA' '-flagB"'`, simply putting single quotes in at every space.

Comment: @Viktor Dahl: It turns out we just used the wrong syntax. You have to write `"-with-rtsopts=-N -g1"`, with the quotes on the very outside. [This is the related discurrion on Github](https://github.com/haskell/cabal/pull/1346).

Answer (score 2):

If you happen to use [`hpack`](https://github.com/sol/hpack/) to generate `foo.cabal` from `package.yaml`, this is the YAML syntax to use:

```yaml
executables:
  foobar:
    main: Main.hs
    source-dirs: app
    ghc-options:
      - -threaded
      - -rtsopts
      - '"-with-rtsopts=-N -T"'
      - -Wall

    dependencies:
      […]
```

The string `"-with-rtsopts=-N␣-T"` should become *one single* argv item of the eventual `ghc` process.

Since YAML has quoted string literals too — both layers of escaping are necessary.