# Cabal config for compiler flags and runtime options

Tags: haskell, cabal

I'm trying to get a cabal config equivalent to compiling with `ghc -threaded -O2` then running with `my.exe +RTS -N4 -s`. Currently I have

```
executable my.exe
   ghc-options: 
        -O3
        -threaded
        -rtsopts
        -with-rtsopts="-N4"
   main-is: Main.hs
```

When I run `my.exe` it gives me `unexpected RTS argument: -N4`

Comment: Have you tried it without the quotes around the `-N4`?  [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6505648/building-with-runtime-flags-using-cabal-and-ghc) seems very similar to yours.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For multiple options, put the entire field in quotes:

> "-with-rtsopts=-N4 -s"

Alternatively, you can add each option seperately:

> -with-rtsopts=-N4
>
> -with-rtsopts=-s

Comment: But doing `-N4 -s` does not work. how do I add `-s` ?

Comment: Sorry, I overlooked the -s flag. I think adding another line will do the trick, but I'd be happy to hear about a single line solution.

Comment: Put the entire thing in quotes - "-with-rtsopts=-N4 -s"

Comment: Oh, that's nice, wouldn't have thought of that :) Thanks, I updated the answer accordingly.